# Set theory: $B$ without $A$ equals $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given two sets $A$ and $B$. We know that $B \setminus A = B$ holds. What can we say about the relation between $A$ and $B$?

I would say that $ A \cap B = \{ \}$ must hold in order to respect the original relation. Is this true?

Comment: Your observation is correct. Now, can you prove it? You know that $B \backslash A \subset B$ is true always. When is the other way true?

Comment: Try to find a contradiction on base of the assumption that $x\in A\cap B$.

Comment: Well, $A = \{ \}$ would also be a possible explication. ;)

Comment: @JohnD: But then $A\cap B=\varnothing$ still.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Right.  $A=\{ \}$ is just a "special" case, while $A \cap B = \{ \}$ always holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in A \cap B$, then $x \in B$, hence $x \in B \setminus A$, therefore $x \notin A$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

A bit formal:

Let $A,B \subset X$.

$B$ \ $A= B\cap A^c$ , where $A^c$ is the complement of $A$ in $X$.

Given : $ B$ \ $A = B\cap A^c =B$;

Then

$(B\cap A^c) \cap A= B \cap  A$;

$B\cap (A^c\cap A)= B\cap A$;
(Associative law)

$B \cap \emptyset =B\cap A$;

$B\cap A =\emptyset$.